# Xcode is using ruby 2.7 but terminal version shows 2.6

Tags: ruby, xcode, homebrew

I want to apologise in advance if I  write somethings that are not accurate enough as I may lack of knowledge.

I am working on a new Mac Mini M1 machine and I am using Xcode 12.2.1 on Monterrey. During the environment setup, I installed homebrew and I may (not sure) also installed ruby.

The Xcode project that I am trying to build has a build phase executing a ruby file and I see the following error:

[image]

When using my terminal, if I run **which ruby** and **which -a ruby** I see the following output.

[image]

But when I run **ruby -v** I see:

[image]

and when I run **gem env**

[image]

At this point I am confused

- Which version is the system version and which one is the homebrew (If any)
- Do I have 2 versions of ruby installed?
- Why **Xcode** and **which** returns 2.7 but **ruby --version** returns 2.6

Comment: Looks like you didn't configure rbenv correctly. Configure it.

Comment: @matt Thank you for the information. However, I am still unsure how to do that. So, version 2.6 is the one that osX provided and 2.7 the one from homebrew? I have found this https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-ruby-on-rails-with-rbenv-on-macos#introduction but I can't figure it out

Comment: See my https://www.biteinteractive.com/how-to-get-started-with-pods/ to learn how to use rbenv to install your own ruby.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Matt's [article](https://www.biteinteractive.com/how-to-get-started-with-pods/), I was able to figure out that:

- /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework is the folder where the one provided by apple is located.
- Homebrew installs rbenv which is used to manage ruby versions
- If I run **rbenv versions** then I get which versions of ruby are installed.

[image]

Then from here I follow the steps to select a new ruby version:

```
% rbenv global 2.7.3
% rbenv rehash
% rbenv init
% cd
% echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' >> .zshrc
```